# What is "The Story of China" film within the film?

Tags: documentary, the-story-of-china

In Michael Wood's "The Story of China" documentary (BBC 2016 / PBS 2017) - frequently when the documentary discusses various warring provinces or groups the film cuts to what appears to be a commercially produced (most likely Chinese) movie depicting a historical battle. What is this film?

Answer (score 1):

According to the credits, the film clips used in "The Story of China" are from 
[Saving General Yang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saving_General_Yang), a 2013 film.